# Use AutoFac with Web API Controller and Multiple Contructor Parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have two Web API controllers that each have the same two contructor parameters as follows:

```
public SystemController(IResourceFactory pResourceFactory, IHttpRequestProcessor pRequestProcessor)

public VersionsController(IResourceFactory pResourceFactory, IHttpRequestProcessor pRequestProcessor)
```

I would like to be able to pass in different implementations for `IHttpRequestProcessor`. Is this possible with AutoFac resolver? If so, how would I register these controllers. Currently I am only using the simple registration call:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

I also tried registering each dependency after making this call, here's what I tried:

```
        builder.Register(c => new ResourceFactory()).Named<IResourceFactory>("ResourceFactory").As<IResourceFactory>().InstancePerApiRequest();
        builder.Register(c => new SystemValidator()).Named<IHttpRequestProcessor>("SystemValidator").As<IResourceFactory>().InstancePerApiRequest();
        builder.Register(c => new VersionsValidator()).Named<IHttpRequestProcessor>("VersionsValidator").As<IResourceFactory>().InstancePerApiRequest();
```

The part I am not sure about is whether I can now tell AutoFac which instance to use for IHttpRequestProcessor.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: did you try registering individually such dependency, I would try some thing like. builder.Register(c => new SystemController(c.Resolve<IHttpRequestProcessor>()));

Comment: Yes, I tried registering each dependency following the RegisterApiControllers call.

Comment: builder.Register(c => new SystemController(c.ResolveNamed<IResourceFactory>("ResourceFactory"), .....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
builder.Register(c => new SystemController(c.ResolveNamed<IResourceFactory>("ResourceFactory"), .....)
```